# What is the recommended approach of capturing the state of the component in URL in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, url-routing, angular-routing

I have the reusable widget which has its own state. In my case the state consists of the **content of the search bar (2)**, **one or more select boxes (1)**, and the **tree where the user can pick the currently active element (3)**.

I want to implement the locationManager which would do two things:

- set `$location` and change the URL based on state of the widget
- read the URL entered and set the widget into a proper state

I wonder if there is some kind of design pattern specific to the angular applications for this problem. My idea is to communicate the state using the events: every time the state of the widget changes it should emit the event which will be captured by the location manager and the URL will be set accordingly. Is there a better way?

UPD: the question is mostly about AngularJS 1, but Angular 2 solutions are also appreciated.

[image]

Comment: AngularJS 1.x or Angular2?

Comment: an advice for any of them would be great

Comment: They are entirely different frameworks. You should decide for one.

Comment: `window.location.href` should work for both though (I don't know AngularJS 1.x)

Comment: I'm asking for the advice about the architecture, not the code. Should it be the responsibility of the router? Should I manage the state through something like events and redux container? How the data flow should go to minimize the code duplication?

Comment: There is a router in both Angular versions that does that for you.

Comment: Please presume that I know how to work with router, $location and other tools in both Angular 1 and 2+

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138032/discussion-between-ganqqwerty-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need use queryParams from service ActivatedRoute.
[Update query params in the browser url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yt9BR.png)

[Make behavior for chnging queryParams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wL6ya.png)

Comment: Great, so that will be one-directional data flow through the router, and all of the components will listen to the changes in the url parameters. Cool, seems to be pretty clean.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. In case those links become invalid though, please include the important information from the links in your post.